# Run a PHP function if returned SQL data matches a specific value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to run a function if the returned data from database matches a specific value.
For example, if **`SELECT city FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`** returns "**London**" then run the PHP function 'myFunction()'.
**What I tried is :**

```
// Database connected successfully
$abc = "SELECT city FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
if ($abc = "London") {
myFunction();
}
else{
echo("not found");
}
```

Comment: You're not executing the query  or fetching the results.

Comment: Read a tutorial on how to perform SQL queries in PHP.

Comment: ALso use `==` for comparison. `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow these steps.

```
//build database connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

//query
$query = "SELECT city FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

//execute query
$resultSet = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet); // as we have limit 1 in query so only one record will be returned in result set

if($record['city'] == 'London'){
    //call function
    myFunction();
}else{
    echo "Not found!";
}
```